# For loops in ocaml

Tags: for-loop, graph, ocaml

I want to do something  like

```
let switchgraph cases =

let g = Graph.makeGraph() in
let g = (Graph.addNode g 1) in
for i = 2 to cases do 
    let g = (Graph.addNode g i) in
done
g
```

But apparently, this is not possible. How else can i achieve this.

Comment: `let rec loop i gr = if i = cases then gr else loop (i + 1) (Graph.addNode gr i) in loop 0 (Graph.makeGraph ())`. Or assign to a `ref`.

Comment: I would upvote that answer, except it's a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix:

- you need to use references (see `ref`, `:=` and `!`) for this, since `let` bindings are immutable
- to sequence two expressions, you need to use `;`

Something like this should work:

```
let switchgraph cases =
    let g = ref (Graph.makeGraph()) in
    g := Graph.addNode (!g) 1;
    for i = 2 to cases do
        g := Graph.addNode (!g) i
    done;
    !g
```

Note that `g` is the reference, and `!g` the value.